Why is MongoDB Atlas Vector Store not returning records when doing a similarity search while running locally?
I am working on a simple RAG using Spring AI and my MQTT server project available here. I swear I had it working once but I didn't commit and now it isn't working again. Basically I think this issue is with the vectorstore. I say that because here
public void updateSmartHomeVectors() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String smartHomeJson = haNetworkCache.getSmartHomeJson();
        List<Document> documents = tokenizeSmartHomeStatus(smartHomeJson);
        vectorStore.add(documents);
        logger.warn("Smart Home Vectors Updated");
}

When I break point on the last line I see

But when I try to confirm they were added using vectorStore.similaritySearch(SearchRequest.query("door").withTopK(5)) I get a result of 0 even though I see things like

in mongo. And when I try to ask it a question I get

I'm sorry, but I can't determine what devices are available without additional context or >specific information about your setup. Please provide more details or check your smart >home app or hub for a list of connected devices.

What am I missing why is it not seeing the rag info
Update
I did notice this thread wait but when I tried to copy and paste the exact code from the test...
List<Document> documents = List.of(
    new Document(
        "Spring AI rocks!! Spring AI rocks!! Spring AI rocks!! Spring AI rocks!! Spring AI rocks!!",
        Collections.singletonMap("meta1", "meta1")),
    new Document("Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World"),
    new Document(
        "Great Depression Great Depression Great Depression Great Depression Great Depression Great Depression",
        Collections.singletonMap("meta2", "meta2")));

vectorStore.add(documents);
Thread.sleep(5000); // Await a second for the document to be indexed

List<Document> results = vectorStore.similaritySearch(SearchRequest.query("Great").withTopK(1));

the results are still empty
So I tried adding the sources to debug
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4' // Use the latest stable version
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'idea'
}

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

Ok I got the aggregate query from adding debug logging and create this script
And it appears to be something from the Mongo side because I get
jgleason@BigBoy ~/code/spring-ai-example -  (ADD_MQTT_SUPPORT) $ mongosh "mongodb://admin:password@10.0.0.58:30087/wiki?authSource=admin" app/debug/mongodb/test-count.js
Connected to database: wiki
Collections in this database: ["vector_store"]
Document count in vector_store: 12295
No matches found

Update 2
I tried to make a minimalist example based on this available here but it still won't return the documents properly.

I noticed that you searched for door via similaritySearch whereas Door is with an upper D. Could it be a problem related to case-sensitivity? If you search for Door instead, do you get results?

I did try changing the case and I still couldn't get it to work. To avoid weirdness like that I tried to copy directly from the Spring and Mongo Docs and I am seeing the same issue in the minimalist version

Are you doing the following? - Because I do not see this in your question - what exactly is your code?
/controller/Controller.java
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<Map<String, Object>> searchDocuments() {
    List<Document> results = vectorStore.similaritySearch(
            SearchRequest
                    .query("learn how to grow things")
                    .withTopK(2)
    );
    return results.stream().map(doc -> Map.of(
            "content", doc.getContent(),
            "metadata", doc.getMetadata()
    )).collect(Collectors.toList());
} 



As I said the full example is in the final link. https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-ai-example/blob/MIN/app/src/main/java/org/example/controller/ChatController.java#L82
